# jquery select class with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to use the html `data-*` attributes and have some images like this:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100.png" data-selected="true">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100.png" data-selected="false">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100.png" data-selected="false">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100.png" data-selected="true">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100.png" data-selected="false">
```

how can i now just only get the ones with `data-selected="true"`?

I tried:

```
$("img").each(function(){
  if($(this)).attr("data-selected") == "true") {
    //do something
  }
}
```

but this seems not to be the best way to me. Is there a direct selector where i can do something like

```
 $("img data-selected=true") ?
```

thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please note that jQuery has **excellent** [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$("img[data-selected='true']")` but quoting of value isn't obligatory.

PS: it is called `CSS attribute selector`.

Comment: Its called the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 8):

Well for one thing you should use `.data(...)`

```
$("img").each(function(){
  if($(this)).data("selected") == "true") {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Or you can use:

```
$("img[data-selected='true']").something...
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer to `.data()` im forever writing "use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`" on here !!!

Comment: oh, didn't thought about .data() will do that!

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
$("img[data-selected='true']")
```

This uses the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use attribute selector

```
$("img[data-selected='true']");
```

Other alternative is `filter()`

```
$("img").filter(function(){ return $(this).data("selected") == "true" });
```

Note that to access data attributes you can use `data()` method and you just have to pass the second half of the data attribute name.

Comment: Ahhh `.filter()`! I was trying to remember the name of that function! `+1` :-)

Comment: cool so many posibilities !! will try that too altought the first one would be shorter :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following selector

```
$('img[data-selected="true"]')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$("img[data-selected='true']")
```

there are a lot of more selectors than just tags and classes. See [here on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 2):

This is some way to do this without using jQuery:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

imgs.​​​​​map(function (img) {
    if (img.attributes["data-selected"].value == "true") {
        // do something
    }
});​
```

And you don't need jQuery!

Comment: yep; but here it comes native version: `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` :) And no more jQuery

Comment: In that case its better if you modify your answer with alternative approach without using `Javascript`.